# @JsonView with Spring PagedResources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I've a pojo exposed with Rest Controller. I need to hide some properties for one GET request, so I decided to use jackson's annotation @JsonView. I can't find any way to made it with @JsonView and PagedResources.

Here is my pojo :

```
public class Pojo {

     interface RestrictedPojo {}
     interface AllPojo extends RestrictedPojo {}

     @Id
     @JsonView(RestrictedPojo.class)
     private String identifier;

     @JsonView(AllPojo.class)
     private String someproperty;

     /**
      * Property I want to hide
      */
     @JsonView(RestrictedPojo.class)
     private String someHiddenProperty;
}
```

Here is my Controller :

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/pojo")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class PojoController {

    private final PojoService pojoService;

    private final IdentityUtils identityUtils;

    private final PagedResourcesAssembler<Pojo> pagedResourcesAssembler;

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('SOME_ROLE')")
    @GetMapping
    @JsonView(Pojo.RestrictedPojo.class)
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Pojo>>> getAllRestrictedPojos(final Pageable pageable) {
        final Page<Pojo> allPojo = pojoService.getAllRestrictedPojos(pageable);
        final PagedResources<Resource<Pojo>> resources = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(allPojo );
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('SOME_ROLE')")
    @GetMapping
    @JsonView(Pojo.AllPojo.class)
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Pojo>>> getAllPojos(final Pageable pageable) {
        final Page<Pojo> allPojo = pojoService.getAllRestrictedPojos(pageable);
        final PagedResources<Resource<Pojo>> resources = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(allPojo );
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
    }
}
```

I didn't wrote specific config, it's a basic spring boot app.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: When you put  `@JsonView(RestrictedPojo.class)` over the field, you put it in json. If you want to hide the field, you do not need to annotate him.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear. I need to implement solution explained here : https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring